# Notification download for XChat with Unity?

Tags: 11.10, unity, notification, xchat

I want to be notified when a download is active in XChat like Firefox is a little "1" and a progression bar, is that possible with XChat?

I want that:

[image]

But I want it for XChat!

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't see that feature in the Xchat shipped with Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no one developed the feature. Thus, it wasn't shipped.